# how can I perform some logic on resolved model depending on previous route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's imagine that I have `Articles` resource and `Article` one with dynamic segment.

`ArticlesRoute` and `ArticleRoute` load `Article` using the same underlying data. But `ArticlesRoute` uses basic data using different serializer - the point is to not load all articles, relations, and other not essential data in index.

Using e.g link pointing to `/articles/5` (from index) transition to `ArticleRoute` with full data. model for `link-to` helper uses explicit `id` to trigger `model` hook:

```
link-to 'article', this.id
```

The model is fired but what in store is, is only basic data. I'd like to invoke `reload` (to load full data) only if I'm transitioning from `ArticlesRoute` - I want to have `LoadingRoute`.

If I call `model.reload()` in `afterModal` there's a delay before template changes (no loading route)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the state of ember-data partially loaded records is. As I recall it was on some wish list.  I have had success doing it like so.

Instead of calling reload or find I do a query. In order to make the route model hook fire I always pass a primitive to the route (like you are doing in link-to).

here is what my model hook looks like.

```
model: function(params) {
  var query;

  query = {
    id: params.id, 
    includes: ['users'], 
    fields: ['name', 'date', 'user.name', 'user.whatever']
  };

  return this.store.find('article', query).then( 
    function(results) {
      return results.get('firstObject')
    }
  );
}
```

Hope this helps.